# How to leave the execute prompt in zsh

Tags: zsh, prompt

In a zsh, maybe I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> by mistake,
but now I'm stuck and this `execute: _` prompt won't leave.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does nothing. 
If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it tries to complete what I typed.

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line:

```
execute: _
zsh: do you wish to see all 373 possibilities (64 lines)?
```

Typing `q` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
execute: quote_
quoted-insert  quote-line     quote-region
```

In other shells, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> brings the same behavior,
except that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> cancels the prompt.

Is there a way to get out or is this shell dead?

Comment: Are you sure you get the prompt for showing all possibilities on **Ctrl+C**? Usually this should close the "execute:" prompt. I only get this prompt on **Enter** (on an empty line) and **Escape**. As far as I can see from the manpage, this is also seems to be not configurable.

Comment: I've got the same problem and I have an ominous feeling I have mapped the key to get out of this to something else

Comment: @Sevenearths did you set any TRAP that you forgot to clear ? Your comment reminded me how I solved this bug (I think).

Comment: Does anyone know what this mode is called or how to actually use it?

Comment: It's called `execute-named-cmd`, triggered by in `:` in normal mode if you're using vim bindings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> aborts the current editing command in [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html) and [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Miscellaneous) if you are in Emacs mode (which is usually the default mode).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Small note...  `Ctrl`+`g` seems to work in vi mode too.

Comment: thank you! while we are at it - sometimes (with vi mode enabled, dunno if related) I get stuck with a bad command which I can't cancel with `Ctrl-C` anymore, any quick ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ everything, to see the behavior.

When I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,
the terminal emulator told me that output was blocked. 
Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to enable output back,
and my prompt came back to normal.

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> again, I have the same problem, but if I execute a zsh internal command it does it.

That's actually the current terminal / shell that doesn't receive <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I don't know why.

Edit from some time after (Oct 2017): It's probable that I had this bug due to a `TRAP INT` set up in my shell during some function and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

```
ctrl + c
```

is working for me, using

```
ctrl + g
```

will print

```
^g
```

on my terminal

Comment: Are you willing to give your computer to lolesque (the OP)?  Because otherwise, telling what works on your computer isn’t any help to them, or to anybody else who has the same problem, inasmuch as the question says “Pressing Ctrl+C does nothing”.